# Database Connection Failed - Error

Tags: mysql, fatal-error

I need help with sorting out this error. We purchased a website through sites and stores and just states "Upload your website files provided". I have done this directly into our CPanel and this is the error i have received:

```
Database Connection Failed
Error: Access denied for user 'healthinsurancea'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (1045)
Function Performed: CONNECT
Host/DB: localhost/healthinsurancea_db
Database Type: mysqli

Fatal error: Attempt to connect to database healthinsurancea_db on healthinsurancea@localhost failed in /home/healthin/public_html/lib/adodb.functions.php on line 61
Database Connection Failed
Error: Access denied for user 'healthinsurancea'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (1045)
Function Performed: CONNECT
Host/DB: localhost/healthinsurancea_db
Database Type: mysqli

Fatal error: Attempt to connect to database healthinsurancea_db on healthinsurancea@localhost failed in /home/healthin/public_html/lib/adodb.functions.php on line 61
```

Please inform me how to resolve this... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

CPanel has an option, maybe with name 'remote database' or something similar. You should add your IP to this list where you tried to connect to it from.